# Notation: need help to understand the notation in the following formula

Tags: optimization, notation, summation

[image]

E is just a function such that E1=1, E2=2 and so on. 
But my question is the part of on "arg" and "min".

1) so "arg" stands for the angle of complex number? this doesn't make any sense.

2）If I use a "min" in front of a summation, do I only take the minimum terms of the entire summation?

3) If you look understand the "min", there is "i:s_i

Comment: The formatting appears to be done quite badly on this expression, it should look more like: $$i_{n}=\operatorname{argmin}\limits_{i:s_{i}<T;\; s_{i} > s_{i_{n}-1}}\left\{\frac{\sum_{j=i_{n}-1}^{i-1}E_{j}}{s_{i}-s_{i_{n}-1}}\right\}$$ Where $\operatorname{argmin}$ corresponds to the argument (seemingly $i$) to the function to produce the minimum.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Comment: @Rahul, can you briefly explain the argmin function?

Comment: $\operatorname{\arg\min}\limits_{x} f(x)$ means the value of $x$ which minimizes $f(x)$. It's the *argument* of the function at which it attains its *minimum*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the sum is over the index $j$, so the terms in the sum will be $E_{i_{n-1}} + E_{i_{n-1} + 1} + \cdots + E_{i-1}$. The minimum is then taken over the index $i$, so you choose an $i$ such that the sequence, divided by the $s_i - s_{i_{n-1}}$ term, is minimal. The stuff underneath the min put additional constraints on the $i$, i.e. that $s_i$ is less than some $T$ and that the denominator is positive. I have no idea what the arg is doing. Hope this helps a bit.

Edit: As user Shaktal pointed out, it's actually the argmin function. (I hadn't heard of it before.) The formatting is just bad.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to be $\operatorname{argmin}(\cdot)$ of the expression rather than $\arg( \min(\cdot))$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I hadn't seen that function before.

Comment: " The minimum is then taken over the index i, so you choose an i such that the sequence, divided by the si−sin−1 term, is maximal", In the last word of the sentence,I guess you mean "minimum"?

Comment: Yep. My bad. Ninja edit made.